# Funky Rear Axle. Need help Identifying

Tags: axle, rear-wheel, quick-release

I recently bought a Globe Work 2, and I'm digging it, but I'm at a loss for what is going on with my rear axle.  I took a couple of pics (below), so I'm hoping someone can tell me what I've got.

According to the spec sheet, I'm supposed to have "REAR HUBDouble-sealed, loose ball, dual-lock nuts, steel axle, QR, 32h", but that doesn't look like a QR to me, and I don't know what dual-lock nuts are.

So, any ideas about what this is?

[image: Pic 1]
[image: Pic 2]

Comment: Someone installed "pegs" on the rear axle, possibly replacing the axle in the process.

Comment: I don't think they're pegs.  They spin.

Comment: Is it removable with a normal tool on both ends?  I can't see from the pics how you're supposed to turn/hold the right.   I'm wondering about a security feature, as they both spin, which stops you getting a wrench on them.

Comment: That's the thing.  Allen wrench in one side, but I have no idea how to hold the other side.  That entire casing spins freely and that hole is just a smooth circle with no connection point inside.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like an attaching point for some kind of trailer, maybe a single wheel trailer.

Comment: In any event, the devices can probably be removed.  Certainly a new skewer would be needed, and it may be necessary to replace the axle itself, but those are relatively inexpensive items.

Comment: Hmm.  That stinks.  I bought it new at the LBS.  Sounds like they scavenged parts or something.  A return trip is in order.

Comment: @CJF if it's new then definitely take it back. If nothing else they should be able to explain what those things are for (please report back so we all know - you can answer your own question).

Comment: I took it in to the shop today and they said it was in fact for a trailer.  They had set up my bike to demo the trailer and forgot to switch the skewer back when they sold it to me.  Mystery solved!